# How to unpack bytes using struct module in python?

Tags: c, struct, python-3.x

I'm trying to unpack  bytes in python :-

```
import struct


c_struct_exp='struct lokesh { int i=5;} lm;'
result=struct.unpack('!i',bytes(c_struct_exp,'utf-8'))  
print(result)
```

error:

```
 struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 4
```

please, help me with format string expression in unpack method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`unpack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) is for unpacking **binary data**, not C source code. To follow your example of single integer member structure:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('i', 134)
'\x86\x00\x00\x00'
>>> unpack('i', '\x86\x00\x00\x00')
(134,)
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not using C source code directly. I'm converting c source code into raw bytes :- bytes(c_struct_exp,'utf-8')  before using it in unpack methode..

Comment: Try printing the output of your `bytes(...)` call - it's still *source code*. `unpack` decodes *memory image* of a structure, not its source description.

Comment: okk :) got it... actually i'm trying to decode a C struct packet from a C client at server side(python receiving end).. how can i can decode unpack received raw bytes(C struct,which is memory image and not a source code at client side)... how can i unpack a structure of the above type :- `typedef struct packet{ int command; union{ struct{int data[100]; int ttl[100];}; struct{ char config[256]; };};} myPacketStruct;`